# Parallelogram area using only diagonals and one side

Tags: geometry, area

**Question:**

> Diagonals of parallelogram are $6$ and $8$ cm. If one side is $5$ cm, then area of parallelogram is ?

**My attempt:**

Construct $AH$ perpendicular to base.

[image]

Let $DB = 6 cm$ and $AC = 6cm$. Since diagonals of parallelogram bisect each other $AO = OC = 4 cm$ and $OB = OD = 3cm$. But, I don't know where to proceed from where. I have an instinct that probably the AH segment will be used in the solution but I can't just connect to the solution.

Thus, I need help in this problem (hints are most welcome!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $(3,4,5)$ is a [Pythagorean triple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple).

If it wasn't a Pythagorean triple, you could use [Heron's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) to get the area of triangle $OAD$, and then use the fact that triangles $OAD$ and $ODC$ have the same area: equal base ($AO=OC$) and equal height (perpendicular distance of $D$ from $AC$).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the comments, I think this might help. The area of a parallelogram is $\frac {d_1d_2 \sin {\theta}}{2} .$ Here $d_1$ and $d_2$ are the lengths of the respective diagonals and $\theta$ is the angle between the two diagonals. Since $3-4-5$ is a right triangle, here $\theta=90°$. And hence our answer will be ${\frac {1}{2}}\cdot 8\cdot 6\cdot 1=24$ square units.